# REGEX para determinar una serie de patrones en una hoja de texto

Tags: javascript, sql-server, regex, txt

En total tengo una serie de datos similares a los de la tabla y por ello requiero identificar ya sea con una o varias expresiones regulares que obtengan el **resultado esperado**

| Los datos de mi hoja de texto | El resultado esperado |
| --- | --- |
| RacePosition 853 | 853 |
| RacePosition 1355 OFI-02-201A | 1355 |
| Race Of Nov/2020 TO LINE 57SA000C-0002876 | 2876 |
| Race to 123/ASDON | 123 |
| Race to2087/ASDON CC 09.07.2020 | 2087 |
| RacePosition CCF 57SA000C-0001234 | 1234 |
| Race Of 6590 of 03/09/2020 | 6590 |

La plataforma que uso por el momento es Visual Studio Code y SQL Server

Comment: Tiene algún requisito de plataforma? tiene que ser excel? o es en python?, en la etiqueta veo javascript, sql... cuál de todas?

Comment: Hola @Alonso, bienvenid@ a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es relativamente complicado porque realmente no hay un patrón único, lo que puedes hacer es tener varios regex e ir pasando en orden de prioridad hasta que uno calce.

Puedo identificar tres regex:

1. Solo números sin símbolos raros alrededor
2. números luego de un `to` o de un `of`
3. números con el formato `000####`

Con eso haría 3 expresiones regulares:

1. Solo números sin símbolos raros alrededor: `/^.*\s([0-9]+)(\s.+)?$/` Sacar grupo 1.
2. números luego de un `to` o de un `of`:  `/^.*(of|Of|to)\s?([0-9]+).*$/` Sacar grupo 2
3. números con el formato `000####`: `/^.*0{3}([0-9]{4}).*$/` Sacar grupo 1

Si todo está bien quedaría así:

```js
const testData=[{data:"RacePosition 853",result:853},{data:"RacePosition 1355 OFI-02-201A",result:1355},{data:"Race Of Nov/2020 TO LINE 57SA000C-0002876",result:2876},{data:"Race to 123/ASDON",result:123},{data:"Race to2087/ASDON CC 09.07.2020",result:2087},{data:"RacePosition CCF 57SA000C-0001234",result:1234},{data:"Race Of 6590 of 03/09/2020",result:6590}];


function test1(str) {
  const regex = /^.*\s([0-9]+)(\s.+)?$/
  const groups = regex.exec(str);
  if(groups != null) {
    return groups[1];
  }
  return undefined;
}
function test2(str) {
  const regex = /^.*(of|Of|to)\s?([0-9]+).*$/;
  const groups = regex.exec(str);
  if(groups != null) {
    return groups[2];
  }
  return undefined;
}

function test3(str) {
  const regex = /^.*0{3}([0-9]{4}).*$/;
  const groups = regex.exec(str);
  if(groups != null) {
    return groups[1];
  }
  return undefined;
}


function searchNumber(str) {
  const tests = [test1, test2, test3];

  let result = undefined;
  
  for(let i=0; i<tests.length; i++) {
    const test = tests[i];
    result = test(str);
    if(result!==undefined) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

testData.forEach(it => {
  const result = searchNumber(it.data);
  console.log(it.data + ": " + result);
})
```